Aerospike DB trace details and location of the trace
Do we have any mechanism to find DB trace/query especially when CRUD operation happens? Like traces that were called/executed at the back just before or at outage timeframe? still trying to see if we can open DB trace and see the calls happened inside DB say in this case Delete operation during outage.
Like the one in SQL/Oracle DB query trace
Do we have any mechanism to find DB trace/query especially when CRUD operation happens? Like traces that were called/executed at the back just before or at outage timeframe? still trying to see if we can open DB trace and see the calls happened inside DB say in this case Delete operation during outage.

There are two ways to track what happened in the CRUD operations at Aerospike.
The first is to use the audit trail and capture data related operations (https://aerospike.com/docs/server/operations/configure/security/access-control#audit-trail). 
The second one is to enable traces in the log files - which can be done at various levels (https://aerospike.com/docs/server/operations/configure/logging/aerospike-logs#dynamically-changing-the-severity-level). One of those traces can be for the rw-client which will log every digest used:
Jul 11 2024 07:54:36 GMT: DETAIL (rw-client): (thr_tsvc.c:99) {test} digest a443f05d05d962202b59abb402afae1737dbf66a client 172.17.0.1:51334 write
Jul 11 2024 07:55:10 GMT: DETAIL (rw-client): (thr_tsvc.c:99) {test} digest a443f05d05d962202b59abb402afae1737dbf66a client 172.17.0.1:45160 read
Jul 11 2024 07:55:29 GMT: DETAIL (rw-client): (thr_tsvc.c:99) {test} digest a443f05d05d962202b59abb402afae1737dbf66a client 172.17.0.1:56552 delete

(in the above example, a record was created, read, and deleted)
Just be aware that in a high throughput use case those logs can be very very verbose, will increase the size of your log files significantly and might hinder performance.
See also: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-change-log-levels-in-aerospike/2915
